# Common Lisp Exercises/Problems

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm working through Practical Common Lisp presently

http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/

It's an excellent book with some practical assignments towards the end, but I'm looking for basic problems that explore the use of functions, variables and macros.  Can anybody suggest a suitable resource to work through in order to reinforce the concepts presented?

Comment: Can you change title to something like `Common lisp exercise problems`? coz I think its somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) is a great source of programming problems

also, there is [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Answer (score 5):

You may also want to try the [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) exercises in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 2):

There are great exercises in ANSI Common Lisp the book, http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html, for each chapter. Great book too, my favorite to learn Lisp with and as a reference.